# Windows not updating folders from the OS X drive

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I have installed Windows 8.1 on my MBP through Bootcamp. Sometimes I encounter a strange issue:

- Log into OS X, and move/delete/create some files, e.g. `Desktop\test_file.txt`
- Turn off the machine;
- Turn on again (even after hours) and boot into Windows;
- Look into `D:/Users/user/Desktop`, and there's no `test_file.txt` in it! I can see all other files, but the new entry is not there.

This happens very often, and to get things working I have to log into OS X, do nothing, and log again into Windows (which is quite annoying).

Does any of you know why?
I'm looking for a workaround for, when in Windows, "refreshing" the `D:` contents without having to reboot two times.

I have tried with no success:

1. Actually clicking "Refresh" in the file manager;
2. Move to `D:/Users/user/Desktop` from the command line. Can see all that was before, but no `test_file.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting). The culprit is Windows Fast Startup, that actually hibernates the file structure when turning off, and restores it when re-booting in.

Thus any changes happened between these two steps can't be really percieved by Windows. From what I read, it could even bring to data loss (if only it had write permissions towards my HFS+).

So, either you disable it, or you stick with the problem (but be sure not to have write permissions!). You should also make sure to unmount any external drive before hibernating / turning off Windows, otherwise there's real risk you'll be losing data.

Personally I'm gonna disable it.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Windows 8.1 and Yosemite is the HFS+ drivers installed in Windows do not work very well. In defense of Apple, I have a 2007 iMac and Windows 8.1 is not approved for my model.

I assume you are not using Core Storage. If so, you could try the free drivers from Paragon. See link [HFS+ for Windows® 8/8.1 Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/)

Note: You can test for Core Storage by opening a Terminal application window and entering the following command.

```
diskutil  cs  list
```

If you are not using Core Storage, the result will be

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Comment: Nope I'm using HFS+.

Comment: Oh, thought the drivers were for CoreStorage. So I could use them. But.. I don't feel comfortable using free drivers from a company that is offering paid support in the same page, honestly. Looks like you're gonna have some issue in a short time.

Comment: FYI, Core Storage is a way to partitioning you disk(s). Core Storage volumes usually are formatted HFS+. In your case, I doubt you are using Core Storage because you can already read HFS+ from Windows. What Paragon is also offering the ability to **write** to HFS+ from Windows. The free version only works for Windows 8/8.1. Paid version work with all versions of Windows including Windows 10.

Comment: I just found and posted my answer. Thank you anyway.